# В лесу родИлась ёлочка?

Tags: орфоэпия

Правильно ли тут стоит ударение? Интуитивно кажется, что правильнее было бы на последнем слоге ("Падали листья. Я родилась"). Яндекс в [Словаре ударений](http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/~%D0%A0%D0%BE/2/) говорит, что в значении "появиться на свет" ударение должно быть на последнем слоге, а ударение на втором указывает на другое значение - "появляться", "возникать".

Новый год всё-таки на носу. Хотелось бы разобраться. А то вдруг мы всю жизнь неправильно поём? Допустимо ли понимать этот текст, как "в лесу возникла ёлочка"?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я, кстати, тоже недавно подумала об этом. Но, мне кажется, что тут все просто: ударение сместилось для того, чтобы стихи вписались в мелодию и размер. Не более того.
И офф-топ: достало, что везде сейчас звучит сплошной Jingle bells, когда у нас столько хороших и РОДНЫХ новогодних песен!

Comment: ...и офф-топ: мы, наверное, с вами в каких-то разных мирах живём :-) Я только что из садика, с утренника у ребёнка, где родители с детьми дружно пели именно про НАШУ ёлочку. Вот музыка и навеяла...

Answer (score 3):

Да, такое различие в зависимости от ударения есть. Честно говоря, до Вашего вопроса не знала. Считала правильным ударение на окончании  в любом значении. Знаю правило: в глаголах женского рода прошедшего времени ударение падает на окончание. Исключения: крАла, клАла, послАла.   Не думаю, чтобы автор текста задумывался над оттенками значения. Так легло в строчку, как часто бывает в стихах. 
Но у меня не вызывает доверия почему-то словарь Зарвы. Хотя бы потому, что даже пример поленился другой придумать, как было у Аванесова, так и написал. А уважаемого Аванесова нет уже 30 лет как.

Comment: 1) Вы, наверное, хотели сказать "автор текста" (а не "автор вопроса")?
2) Дословное переписывание Аванесова как раз таки доверие вызывает. Во всяком случае, намного больше, чем нововведения Шведовой ("ячёнок").

А по существу - будем считать это просто ошибкой поэта? как "из пламя и света рождённое слово"? :-)

Comment: ДА. спасибо. исправляю.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько понимаю, это различие идёт от словаря Зарвы (утонение: снимаю, там все корректно), надо сказать, весьма спорно.
До того никаких колебаний не отмечалось. Если ошибаюсь - поправьте.

В отношении песенки. Смещение ударения в принципе возможно. 
Но, если судить по литературе, этого не происходило.

Родила царица в ночь
Не то сына, не то дочь...

Видимо, ударение следует отнести на авторскую вольность.

//-------------------

Я понял, откуда идет это недоразумение со значениями.
Нашел у Ушакова. РодИлась - это несовершенный вид, значение "производить (урожай)".

> ~3. Вырасти (вырастать), произрасти (произрастать), давая урожай. Прежде здесь плохо роди́лась (несов.) пшеница, а после раннего сева в этом году родила́сь (сов.) хорошо.

Конкретно:

Родить(ся) - сов. к рождать(ся): родилась. NN родилАсь 8 марта.
Родить(ся) - несоверш. к "уродить" - производить, воспроизводить: пшеница родИлась хорошо.

Елочка родил**А**сь. Так было, так и осталось поныне.
Так что у Зарвы и последователей некорректная (или плохопонимаемая) формулировка.

**Ларf**, это более всего для Вас, меня тоже посетил небольшой шок от этого род**И**лась в значении "появиться на свет".

> У Аванесова то же самое, что у Зарвы.( родИлась - возникла). Вот это для меня и удивительно!

**Ларf**, это я погрешил на Зарву, у него тоже корректно. Простите великодушно.
Неоднозначность - у Кузнецова

У Аванесова (и Зарвы!) тоже есть пометки "несов" и примеры исключающие ошибочное толкование: "Каждый день у него родИлись новые мысли". Несовершенный вид! Да, возникать, да, **появляться** на свет, но никак не в значении "в лесу родилась елочка", В совершенном виде невозможно. Вернее возможно, но в том смысле, что рождение елочки в лесу было обычным занятием.

В лесу родИлась ёлочка -
И так из года в год
Сомненье с удареньями
Испытывал народ.

Но вот её, красавицу,
Какой-то обормот,
Загнал в статью словарную 
Под плотный переплёт.

И вот она, несчастная,  
В учебники вошла -  
И много всяких трудностей  
Детишкам принесла.

**Ларf**, последняя попытка.

> Но слово "родИлась" в обоих словарях приводится.

Никаких "но"! Да, Приводится. В обоих. Даже - как минимум в трёх: Ушаков, Аванесов, Зарва (Кузнецов не в счет, у него там действительно трудно концы найти). Оно правильно. 
Но правильно это только **в несовершенном виде** и соответвующем значении. Видовой пары родИлась-рождАлась не существует. Есть пара родИлась-уродИлась.
Везде есть примеры, объясняющую эту ситуацию, надо только внимательно читать. У Ушакова оказалась понятнее всех, за что ему и поклон.

Нам трудно произнести родИлась в данном контексте только потому, что там такого быть не может. В значении, соответвующем несовершенному виду ("производить", "появляться на свет", "давать урожай" и т.д.) произнести родИлась мне совсем не сложно.

Comment: @tmp, ударение "родИлась" правильно?

Comment: Оно если и стало стало правильным (в указанном значении), то очень недавно. В старых словарях - родилась.

Comment: хорошо, примем за гипотезу, что оно стало правильным в [переносном] значении "возникла". Вы согласны с тем, что "в лесу родилась ёлочка" можно читать как "в лесу возникла ёлочка"?

Comment: Нет. Не соглассен. Простите, в дискуссиях не участвую.

Comment: Простите, не заметил вовремя существенных изменений вашего основного ответа. Теперь вижу: по сути ответ об авторской вольности совпадает с мнением большинства; это снимает мои вопросы к вам в комментариях.

Comment: Тогда ответите на один личный вопрос? 
Это что же за детский утренник в девять вечера по местному времени?

Comment: Пожалуйста :-). "Утренник" начался часа в 4 (16), пока то да сё, досидели до 18. Потом пришли домой, тоже всякая суета. Ну, и где-то в 19-20 я полез на форум. Согласен, в 21.00 написать "я только что из садика" было некоторым преувеличением. Поэтической вольностью.

Comment: Ну вообще-то вольностью было сказать "утренник" (без кавычек) про посиделки, начинающиеся в сумерки. Ну да Бог Вам судья. Главное ведь это когда тебе верят, да?!

Comment: У Аванесова то же самое, что у Зарвы.( родИлась - возникла).   Вот это для меня  и удивительно!

Comment: Спасибо за внимательное прочтение словарной статьи. Но слово "родИлась" в обоих словарях приводится.Я вот что подумала. Мне кажется, родИлась (именно ж.р. ед. ч., а не множ., как в примере) трудно прочитать с таким ударением, потому что мы (я точно) скорее употреблю в подобном случае "рождАлась" . Что-то вроде "на наших глазах рождалась сказка"